# Counting the frequency of characters by assigning different matrix

Tags: r, matrix, character

I have two matrix, "main" and "label".

```
> main
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    0    0    2    0    1    2    1    1    0     1
 [2,]    0    0    1    0    1    2    2    1    2     1
 [3,]    0    0    0    1    2    0    2    0    2     0
 [4,]    0    0    0    0    2    1    0    2    1     0
 [5,]    0    0    0    0    0    2    1    0    1     2
 [6,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    2    0    1     2
 [7,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1     1
 [8,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     1
 [9,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
[10,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
```

```
> label
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,] "0"  "0"  "G"  "0"  "C"  "G"  "F"  "E"  "0"  "A"  
 [2,] "0"  "0"  "B"  "0"  "D"  "D"  "F"  "G"  "E"  "D"  
 [3,] "0"  "0"  "0"  "E"  "G"  "0"  "D"  "0"  "A"  "0"  
 [4,] "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "A"  "D"  "0"  "F"  "E"  "0"  
 [5,] "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "C"  "H"  "0"  "F"  "G"  
 [6,] "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "F"  "0"  "B"  "F"  
 [7,] "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "F"  "E"  
 [8,] "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "D"  
 [9,] "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  
[10,] "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"
```

By choosing each character in "label" matrix, I want to get the total number of the position of that character in "main" matrix. for example, if I give "B", the output have to be 2 (sum of the numbers in "main" matrix which are in B position) or by giving "A", we have to get 5. It means we will have a list of different kinds of labels with the frequency of each label in main matrix. 
like:

```
A  B  ...
5  2  ...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you can try `xtabs` or `tapply`

```
res <- xtabs(data.frame(c(main),c(label)))
```

or

```
res <- tapply(main,label,sum)
```

**Example**

```
set.seed(1)
main <- matrix(sample(0:2,25,replace = TRUE),nrow = 5)
label <- matrix(sample(c("0",LETTERS[1:3]),25,replace = TRUE),nrow = 5)

res <- xtabs(data.frame(c(main),c(label)))
```

such that

```
> res
c.label.
0 A B C 
6 7 2 6
```

Answer (score 2):

If `data.frame` is the expected format for the result, how about `aggregate`

```
aggregate(main ~ label ,data.frame(main = c(main),label = c(label)),sum)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using *Matrix.utils* package:

```
library(Matrix.utils)

aggregate.Matrix(c(main), c(label), fun = "sum")
```

With [@ThomasIsCoding's Data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61317888/680068):

```
4 x 1 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"

0 6
A 7
B 2
C 6
```